# Parial Zip Code Search autocomplete with Bing Map

Tags: bing-maps

I am using Bing Map to display Pushpins based on addresses I have. But sometimes I may get only Partial Zip Codes in addresses which lead to weird display of map. So I have come up with idea that I will use first matching zip for partial zip code.
e.g. if partial zip code is 640 then retrieve the zip codes those starts with 640 and let say I got **6402342**, 6408678, 640893. Then render pushpin for co-ordinates of first matching zip code that is **6402342**.

So my question is that is there any Bing Map API which could give me the list of matching zip codes as if it gives in autocomplete search box or else is there any better approach to handle partial zip codes on Bing Map.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the rest of the address, try reverse geocoding it's coordinates. It will often return a fairly accurate postal code which would be more accurate than choosing the first zip code from a list. Reverse geocoding can be done using either the REST service: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701710.aspx Or by using the search module in the Bing Maps web control:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712821.aspx

http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk#searchByPoint+JS

If you really want a list of zip codes, you would be best off to download a list from a site and store them. GeoNames has a good collection of Zip codes. Here is a link to the zip file for the US: http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/US.zip

You can find downloads for other countries here: http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/